# How can I invoke a function when a user leaves my site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I'm developing a website in VB.NET/ASP.NET 2.0.

I want to invoke an event (Server Side) once a user leaves my site by putting a different URL in the address bar, is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Are you saying that (for example) I'm on your site and I navigate away from selecting one of my bookmarks, you want to redirect me to another URL instead of my bookmark that I selected?

Answer (score 1):

Invoke the `onbeforeunload` event, like such :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    //Your logic
};
```

Comment: "Your Logic" would have to do a callback to your server to fire the appropriate event on the server.

Comment: If you want to do processing on the server, you would have to use ajax...by sending a request to the server in that onbeforeunload function, because you can't directly invoke a method on the server from the client's page

Comment: Research a bit about Ajax, which allows you to talk to the server without a complete postback (ie without refreshing the page).  That is the only way you can contact the server without a refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` JavaScript event to trigger when a user is about to navigate away from your site.